# Idiom/成語 for "Worrying Doesn't Change the Outcome"

Tags: mandarin, chengyu

Is there an Idiom/成語 for "Worrying does not change the outcome"?

To be used when someone is spending a lot of time / energy worrying about something that they have no control over.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you can provide a context, you may get a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[杞人憂天](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/40877/):

There was a man in Qi always worrying about the sky might fall. People use the term 杞人憂天 to describe someone worry too much, even about the most unlikely events.

Example:

Worry about car accident is one thing, worry about alien invasion or zombie apocalypse is really 杞人憂天

Comment: Thank you -- Exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: 杞人忧天 is a bit different. It's worrying about something unlikely to happen, while OP is asking  "Worrying does not change the outcome".

Comment: OP said 杞人忧天 is what he exactly looking for, I think his meant to ask what idiom describe "worry about something that is unlikely to happen" instead of " worry about something won't change the outcome" In essence -- "uselessly worry"

Comment: OP: when someone is spending a lot of time / energy worrying about something that they have no control over. -- That is sign of 杞人忧天

Comment: Let's say that you take a test and you think you did poorly on it, so are spending a lot of time / energy worrying about the results. The test has already been completed -- there is nothing you can do to change how you did. Does 杞人憂天 fit?

Comment: @user22907 That's not the context 杞人忧天 should be used. 杞人忧天 also implies that you worry something that are not concerning you. In your case, you do concern your test results.

Comment: @user22907 No, it doesn't fit 杞人憂天, Spend time and energy on worrying something you have no control include something that may happen, but most likely won't happen, does fit the description of 杞人憂天. I meant, yes, if the result is already on record and you just don't know it yet, the situation is also out of your control, just for different reason.